# AS400 and Remote Commands

Tags: db2, ibm-midrange

On the AS400 I want to remotely execute:

```
strpgrprg topgr(userx) message(ALERT!)
```

What options are available to me?

update: I want to run a AS400 program from outside of the AS400. I want to execute this command (or similar) from a windows batch, or a linux shell script.

I've found some info on how-to via [FTP](http://forums.systeminetwork.com/isnetforums/showthread.php?t=45254). Just haven't tried it out and still looking to see if it's the best way to do it.

Comment: Can you provide more details? You want to execute a command on the i or on a PC? What would be executing this command?

Comment: updated. Linked something I found that uses FTP. Haven't had a chance to try it out, but still would like to know other options.

Comment: You may get a more knowledgeable audience on Serverfault.

Comment: What @music2myear said.  An AS400 may be a little out of scope for Super User's standard audience, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you want to write a simple Java program using JT400, FTP is probably your best option.

If you want other options, post a message on [MIDRANGE-L](http://murl.me/midrangel) there are around 2,000 people on the list many whom have done this before.

Comment: FTP is easy... now I just gotta merge this with my next question about Exchange Email Account monitoring & Scripting. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

IBM i has a rexec service that you could try using.

To start it, run 'STRTCPSVR SERVER(*REXEC)'

I've never used it myself, but it should work with any rexec client.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can use the `SBMRMTCMD` as well, the only drawbacks would be

1. if the command can only be run in certain modes
2. you cannot prompt the command, as it is passed like a string.

You should do that off the `QCMD` command line, get the parms that you want, then copy and paste.